# Sequelize FindAndCountAll returns SequelizeDatabaseError Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize and MySQL, I am preparing Pagination that returns a list of Products and its associate models including Images, Categories, and SubCategories.

The issue is when I use Product.findAndCountAll() I get an error that column not found but when I use Product.findAll() Sequelize do not complain.

```
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'subCategory.name' in 'where clause'",
```

```
const products = await Product.findAndCountAll({
    distinct: true,
    limit,
    offset,

    attributes: ['identifier','name', 'usage','slug', 'active'],
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            { '$product.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%` }, },
            { '$product.usage$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%` }, },
            { '$subCategory.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%`}, },
            { '$category.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%`} },

        ],
    },
    
    include: [
        { model: Image, as:'images', attributes: ['src', 'altText']},
        { model: Category, as: 'category', attributes: ['name'] },
        { model: SubCategory, as: 'subCategory', attributes: ['name']}
    ],
    logging: console.log
})
```

**ERROR**

```
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
  <rejected> Error
      at Query.run (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:52:25)
      at D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:315:28
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:407:12)
      at async product.findAll (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1140:21)
      at async Promise.all (index 1)
      at async product.findAndCountAll (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1322:27)
      at async module.exports.search (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\controllers\publicController.js:317:22) {
    name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
    parent: Error: Unknown column 'subCategory.name' in 'where clause'
        at Packet.asError (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
        at Query.execute (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
        at Connection.handlePacket (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
        at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
        at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\www.reematec\reema_node\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
        at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
        at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
      code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
      errno: 1054,
      sqlState: '42S22',
      sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'subCategory.name' in 'where clause'",
      sql: "SELECT `product`.*, `images`.`id` AS `images.id`, `images`.`src` AS `images.src`, `images`.`altText` AS `images.altText`, `images->Product_Image`.`createdAt` AS `images.Product_Image.createdAt`, `images->Product_Image`.`updatedAt` AS `images.Product_Image.updatedAt`, `images->Product_Image`.`imageId` AS `images.Product_Image.imageId`, `images->Product_Image`.`productId` AS `images.Product_Image.productId`, `category`.`id` AS `category.id`, `category`.`name` AS `category.name`, `subCategory`.`id` AS `subCategory.id`, `subCategory`.`name` AS 
`subCategory.name` FROM (SELECT `product`.`id`, `product`.`identifier`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`usage`, `product`.`slug`, `product`.`active`, `product`.`categoryId`, `product`.`subCategoryId` FROM `products` AS `product` WHERE (`product`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR `product`.`usage` LIKE '%to%' OR `subCategory`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR `category`.`name` LIKE '%to%') LIMIT 0, 1) AS `product` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `Product_Image` AS `images->Product_Image` INNER JOIN `images` AS `images` ON `images`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`imageId`) ON `product`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`productId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` AS `category` ON `product`.`categoryId` = `category`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `subCategories` AS `subCategory` ON `product`.`subCategoryId` = `subCategory`.`id`;",
      parameters: undefined
    },
```

Below is generated sql statement

```
SELECT 
    count(DISTINCT(`product`.`id`)) AS `count` 
FROM 
    `products` AS `product` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (`Product_Image` AS `images->Product_Image` INNER JOIN 
     `images` AS `images` ON `images`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`imageId`
    ) ON `product`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`productId` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `categories` AS `category` ON `product`.`categoryId` = `category`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `subCategories` AS `subCategory` ON `product`.`subCategoryId` = `subCategory`.`id` 
WHERE 
    (`product`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR `product`.`usage` LIKE '%to%' OR `subCategory`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR `category`.`name` LIKE '%to%');


SELECT 
    `product`.*, 
    `images`.`id` AS `images.id`, 
    `images`.`src` AS `images.src`, 
    `images`.`altText` AS `images.altText`, 
    `images->Product_Image`.`createdAt` AS `images.Product_Image.createdAt`, 
    `images->Product_Image`.`updatedAt` AS `images.Product_Image.updatedAt`, 
    `images->Product_Image`.`imageId` AS `images.Product_Image.imageId`, 
    `images->Product_Image`.`productId` AS `images.Product_Image.productId`, 
    `category`.`id` AS `category.id`, 
    `category`.`name` AS `category.name`, 
    `subCategory`.`id` AS `subCategory.id`, 
    `subCategory`.`name` AS `subCategory.name` 
FROM (
      SELECT 
          `product`.`id`, 
          `product`.`identifier`, 
          `product`.`name`, 
          `product`.`usage`, 
          `product`.`slug`, 
          `product`.`active`, 
          `product`.`categoryId`, 
          `product`.`subCategoryId` 
      FROM 
          `products` AS `product` 
      WHERE 
          (`product`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR 
           `product`.`usage` LIKE '%to%' OR 
           `subCategory`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR 
           `category`.`name` LIKE '%to%'
          ) LIMIT 0, 1) AS `product` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (`Product_Image` AS `images->Product_Image` INNER JOIN 
     `images` AS `images` ON `images`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`imageId`
    ) ON `product`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`productId` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `categories` AS `category` ON `product`.`categoryId` = `category`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `subCategories` AS `subCategory` ON `product`.`subCategoryId` = `subCategory`.`id`;
```

But when I use findAll() I do not get any issue and results are correct only problem is I do not get count of products. below is the query that works correctly.
**No error with findAll**

```
const products = await Product.findAll({
    attributes: ['identifier','name', 'usage','slug', 'active'],
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            { '$product.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%` }, },
            { '$product.usage$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%` }, },
            { '$subCategory.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%`}, },
            { '$category.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${keyword}%`} },

        ],
    },
    
    include: [
        { model: Image, as:'images', attributes: ['src', 'altText']},
        { model: Category, as: 'category', attributes: ['name'] },
        { model: SubCategory, as: 'subCategory', attributes: ['name']}
    ],
    logging: console.log
})
```

**So far what I figured out is that when I use sql count query is root of error.**

SQL Query generated with findAll()

```
(default): SELECT `product`.`id`, `product`.`identifier`, `product`.`name`, `product`.`usage`, `product`.`slug`, `product`.`active`, `images`.`id` AS `images.id`, `images`.`src` AS `images.src`, `images`.`altText` AS `images.altText`, `images->Product_Image`.`createdAt` AS `images.Product_Image.createdAt`, `images->Product_Image`.`updatedAt` AS `images.Product_Image.updatedAt`, `images->Product_Image`.`imageId` AS `images.Product_Image.imageId`, `images->Product_Image`.`productId` AS `images.Product_Image.productId`, `category`.`id` AS `category.id`, `category`.`name` AS `category.name`, `subCategory`.`id` AS `subCategory.id`, `subCategory`.`name` AS `subCategory.name` FROM `products` AS `product` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `Product_Image` AS `images->Product_Image` INNER JOIN `images` AS `images` ON `images`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`imageId`) ON `product`.`id` = `images->Product_Image`.`productId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` AS `category` ON `product`.`categoryId` = `category`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `subCategories` AS `subCategory` ON `product`.`subCategoryId` = `subCategory`.`id` WHERE (`product`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR `product`.`usage` LIKE '%to%' OR `subCategory`.`name` LIKE '%to%' OR `category`.`name` LIKE '%to%')
```

Product

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
    id:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    identifier: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        // unique: true,
    },
    slug:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    showcased:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    recommended:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    active:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    price:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,2),
        allowNull:true
    },
    pagetitle:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    shortDescription:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,        
    },
    LongDescription:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,        
    },
    specifications:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,        
    },
    features:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,        
    },
    care:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,        
    },    
    usage:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },    
    categoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    subCategoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
    },
})

Category.hasMany(Product);
Product.belongsTo(Category);

SubCategory.hasMany(Product);
Product.belongsTo(SubCategory);

Image.belongsToMany(Product, {   through: 'Product_Image' });
Product.belongsToMany(Image, { through: 'Product_Image'});
```

Comment: The subquery that is aliased as ` product` onle selects from product table, yet the where clause references subcategoris table.

Comment: @SalmanA please could you guide me further how to correct it.